# crontab config issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I would like to setup a crontab for my thinking_sphinx search feature.  I am not using any ruby gems for this.

this is my command

```
*/59 * * * * cd path && rake thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=production
```

The syslog gives me this:

```
CRON[2890]: (user) CMD (cd path && rake thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=production)
```

Yet the thinking_sphinx is not getting indexed.  It does work if I index it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I added these at the top of the crontab file, now it works.

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

SHELL=/bin/bash